# Avoid multiple if-else using Java for Xml elements

Tags: java, xml

In the below Java Code for handling xml elements i am using multiple if-else condition. What is the better way to avoid these if-else conditions where I have used "A" and "B" for condition check.

My Code :

```
     ...
        if(((Element)nodeValue).hasAttribute("name")) {
            String nVal = ((Element)nodeValue).getAttribute("name");
            if(nVal.equals("A")) { 
                rNodeContent = nodeValue.getTextContent();                          
                ... Processing...
            } else if(nVal.equals("B")) {
                rNodeContent = nodeValue.getTextContent();
                ... Processing...
            }
        }
     ...
```

Comment: I really can't see you have too many if-else clauses here, when working with files you need to use a lot of checks on the incoming data, we work with these situations a lot and it's really unavoidable to a certain extent.
Only suggestion would be creating a separate method for the nVal.equals check if you want the code to look cleaner

Comment: If you use java 1.7 you can switch on strings. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: DOM is one of the more verbose apis to use; depending on your actual usecase there is likely a better alternative. E.g. if you want to create Object from XML JAXB is a nice fit.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with `nVal`, you might want to create a method that accepts `nVal` and process it there but if you use `if else` inside the method, it won't help either, it really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: The first 2 `if`s can be combined using `&&`

Answer (score 1):

In Java SE 7 and later you may use `switch` statement for several `String` values as it may be a bit more readable:

```
String nVal = ((Element)nodeValue).getAttribute("name");
switch(nVal){
    case "A":
       // processing
       break;
    case "B":
       // processing
       break;
    default:
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid nVal value: " +nVal); 
}
```

Comment: You cannot switch on strings below java 1.7

Comment: @svasa so? If he is using anything older than 7 he should update anyway.

Comment: @Fildor I know many people who still uses jre1.6, what if an old project uses jre1.6 and you need to fix a bug ? and updating it to jre1.7 is not a feasible option or not yet taken up.

Comment: @svasa, I've updated my answer to point on Java version that supports switch for strings